# Javascript onload two functions not returning the data

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, onload

I am trying to display two javascript function when page load. But seems one is overwriting another one.

here is javascript code:

```
function welcome(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
    else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
         document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","php/display_welcome.php", true);
     xmlhttp.send();
}


function testimonial(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
    else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
         document.getElementById("testimonial").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","php/display_testimonial.php", true);
     xmlhttp.send();

}

window.onload = function() {
    welcome();
    testimonial();
};
```

I have 2 div id in the html page.
Also I am using IE9, when I run only one function it works fine, when run two it doesnt return the data.
Hope someone could help me.

Comment: When you run both neither one works?

Comment: Can you check the console and what it prints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot could have gone wrong:

- Non-responsive server
- Bad copy-pasted code
- Syntax errors
- etc.

Anyways, to avoid repepetive code and possible errors even if both code looks the same, I suggest you do this. Since both basically use the same operation, let's factor it out into a single reusable function:

```
function load(url,callback) {

  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
      callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

window.onload = function () {

  load('php/display_welcome.php',function(response){
    document.getElementById("welcome").innerHTML = response;
  });

  load('php/display_testimonial.php',function(response){
    document.getElementById("testimonial").innerHTML = response;
  });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `xmlhttp` without `var` which gives it global scope, that is why it gets over written when you call the second function. Declare it locally and that will not happen. Use var and declare it locally.

```
var xmlhttp;
```